How to check the variable is of certain type
I have a python JSON data and need to iterate through the key pair values and check if the value is of certain type and perform an operation.
here is the example:
total = 0 
grades = {
    'Math': 90,
    'Science': None,
    'English': 85,
    'History': 'A',
    'Art': 88
}

for grade in grades.values():
    total += grade  

i need to check if the value is a number then add to the total.

Often considered more "Pythonic" is to rely on exceptions. So, just perform the addition catch the TypeError, and print out an error.

This question is similar to: What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can check the variable type using isinstance()
like this
for grade in grades.values():
    if isinstance(grade, (int, float)):  # Check if the grade is a number
        total += grade

This will add the values only if the variable is of type int or float

Often considered more "Pythonic" is to use exception handling:
total = 0 
grades = {
    'Math': 90,
    'Science': None,
    'English': 85,
    'History': 'A',
    'Art': 88
}

for grade in grades.values():
    try:
        total += grade  
    except TypeError:
        print (f"ERROR: '{grade}' is not a number!")


You can check the instance of the value and update the total accordingly
total = 0 

grades = {
     'Math': 90,
     'Science': None,
     'English': 85,
     'History': 'A',
     'Art': 88
}

for grade in grades.values():
    if isinstance(grade, (float, int)):
       total += grade
    elif isinstance(grade, str) and grade.isdecimal():
       total += int(grade)
print(total)


You should replace isdigit() with isdecimal(), otherwise if grade is "3²" it will fail.

Updated to use isdecimal()
